# Password System Error

Tags: java, passwords

Hey I'm a new programmer in java and tried making a password system. I would like someone to review the code and give me some advice. The code also has an error I cant figure out so I would need someone to tell me what I did wrong in detail so I don't make the error again. Thanks!

```
package Main;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class ProgramRunner {

public static void main(String [] args){
    Scanner imput = new Scanner(System.in);

    umNoName lol = new umNoName();

    //password
    String password = "pass";
    lol.GetPassword(password);
}

}



package Main;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class umNoName {

public static String password = "pass";
public String Name;

public void simpleMessage(String Name){
    System.out.println("Hello " + Name);
}

public void GetPassword(String password){
    Scanner imput = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Password: ");
    String Password = imput.nextLine();
    if(Password == password){
        simpleMessage(Name);
    }else{
        System.out.print("Password is incorrect!");
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: "The code also has an error I cant figure out " - what is the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some advices:

1. Package name, u should follow some standards (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/namingpkgs.html)
2. Other conventions (Needs to be always remembered, print it and pin to your desk until u get it) (http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html)
3. Keep the right scope for your classes, I suggest u taking a read on Java Object Orientation (Google It)
4. Don't use an public static of a internal used variable, which is not a constant and shouldn't be used outside your class (`password` field)
5. right accessors for the right fields, as, if u have the two password vars (one is the right pass, and the other is the user inputed pass), u must compare it using the .equals (`this.password.equals(password)`)
6. At all, there are some other logical issues that u will get when testing your code.

Hope that been helpful and welcome to java.

Comment: Thanks so much for the advice and help

Answer (score 0):

In the main method the variable password is not defined.

I'm assuming that the 2 classes are in separate files.

Comment: Thanks, I fixed it but now I'm trying to figure out why the password will still not work and it always takes it in as incorrect

Comment: Check the scope of your variables.... password in the method hides the field of the class password.

Answer (score 0):

1. You must enter a name.
2. Create the object and assign the entered name.
3. Call method GetPassword () without parameters.
4. Make the string comparison using the `equals()` method:
   `if (Password.equals(pass))`
5. Follow the instructions of Cristiano Benato.